# Count All incomplete SQL Transactions running on database?

Tags: sql, transactions

I need T-SQL to count Count All incomplete SQL Transactions running on database in another way I need to count all current sql transactions runnging right now on sql server instance.

I hope if I explained well what I need ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I meant [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
```

---

**Original Post**:

As shown on this post here: [SQL SERVER – 2005 -Track Down Active Transactions Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/24/sql-server-2005-track-down-active-transactions-using-t-sql/)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

This is for active transactions on the currently selected database. See [`sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188739%28SQL.100%29.aspx).